# Jekyll blog entries link to only one post

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm not sure what the issue is, but my jekyll blog is acting very differently when I serve it locally vs. when it's loaded on github pages.

When it's served locally, each listed entry links to the correct post in my _posts folder. It works great.

However, when it is viewed on [github pages](http://loganegbert.github.io/blog), it's a very different story. Each and every listed post links to:
/blog/:year/:month/:day/:title which is a replication of the blog posts permalink in the front matter.

And all the links wind up taking me to the top post in the list, despite the code being exactly the same.

I'm guessing this has to do with something missing/amiss in my config.yml but I'm still new enough to this whole process that I can't figure out what. How do I get this blog to work both locally and online?

You can view my code [here.](https://github.com/loganegbert/loganegbert.github.io) If you need any further info, let me know!

Comment: Not an expert but why did you comment out `baseurl: ""` and `url: "http://loganegbert.github.io"` in the `_config.yml` file?

Comment: I think it was simply because i was only developling locally until a few days ago. Never bothered to change it.

I went in and changed it and it doesn't seem to have affected anything.

Comment: Just curious if there was a reason why you cut them out. Are you using permalinks? In that case `permalink: /:title` (or whatever you want it) in the yml file might be missing. Also: IIRC each post should have a different date, not sure if this restriction has been lifted

Comment: i tried setting up github pages on jekyll and had a hard time with it. then, i found Poole (getpoole.com) which is a butler for jekyll. made life much easier

Comment: I am using permalinks. The link that shows up is the exact permalink code in my front matter for each post.

/blog/:year/:month/:day/:title

Comment: @MarcoA. I imagine the date restriction has been lifted. I only say this because all the entries link and load perfectly when served locally.

Comment: @LoganEgbert I had issues with the syntax highlighter on github that I hadn't on my local system. I'm not assuming anything anymore since Jekyll's version might be different on github if they regenerate contents. By the way: give it a try with the `permalink` command properly set and the posts with a different date so we can rule that out.

Comment: @MarcoA. Ok, i'm changing out the post dates. The issue with adding permalink command to the config is that I only want jekyll to handle the permalinking of my blog posts. The page permalinks are set by the fact that i created a folder and an index.html for each.

Comment: @LoganEgbert Actually remove the permalink tag in your posts. The one in the yml file is sufficient. Take a look at [here](https://github.com/marcodiiga/marcodiiga.github.io/tree/master/_posts) and [here](https://github.com/marcodiiga/marcodiiga.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml)

Comment: That did it! I can't wrap my head around the why, but i'm not even going to bother trying to figure it out. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @LoganEgbert Glad it solved your problem. I'll make it an answer for others to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove the permalinks in your posts (they're not needed) and use the permalink command on your yml file formatted as you wish, e.g.

```
permalink: /blog/:title
```

2) Use different dates for different posts. Jekyll used to deal with different-dates posts, not sure if that restriction was lifted